# Ошибка при подключении к MySQL

Tags: php

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/nfwhrbvo/public_html/include/db_connect.php on line 8 Нет соединения с БД

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему....

Основной код вот:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
mysqli_select_db($db_database,$link) or die("Нет соединения с БД " . mysqli_connect_error());
```

Comment: в доки зайди http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.select-db.php и посмотри порядок параметров

Comment: ПОДПРАВИЛ КОЕ ЧТО И ТЕПЕРЬ НА 9 СТРОКУ РУГАЕТСЯ.
 Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/nfwhrbvo/public_html/include/db_connect.php on line 9

Comment: mysqli_query("SET names UTF-8"); 
вот на эту строку

Comment: читай доки... просто читай доки...

Comment: Какие именно,направьте,а?

Comment: Я в этом не шарю просто.перекинул с одного хостинга на другой и полеееезло,полезло

Comment: Ну как какие. по тем методам, которые используешь... http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.select-db.php ....http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php  .... там же написано как должно выглядеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы немного ошиблись, по документации там наоборот:

`mysqli_select_db($link, $db_database)`

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.select-db.php)

А также ошибка будет в `mysqli_query`. Там должно быть:

```
mysqli_query($link, "SET name UTF-8");
```

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/nfwhrbvo/public_html/functions/functions.php:1) in /home/nfwhrbvo/public_html/index.php on line 5
А теперь вот что
строка выглядит вот так 
session_start();

Comment: Это уже не mysql, а сессии :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!подправил и теперь другое появилось)
Warning: Division by zero in /home/nfwhrbvo/public_html/index.php on line 241
и все русские буквы превратились в ????? вроде бы все было в utf-8