# Warning: mysqli_select_db()! ХЕЛП

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/u*******/data/www/********.ru/pages/jobs.php on line 14
Не удается выбрать базу данных!

    if($_POST['act'] == 'nabor'){
    if(!mysqli_connect('localhost','название бд','пароль')) die("Не удается соединиться с сервером баз данных!");
    if(!mysqli_select_db('название бд')) die("Не удается выбрать базу данных!");
    mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )

Comment: дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702170/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba-mysql